# asp/vb.net Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, forms

Hi i am trying to insert data to my User table and also create a user in the ASPNETDB My code is below:

```
  Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim recordsAffected As Integer

    Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT INTO User(Staff_No, First_Name, Surname, Position_Held, Email, Telephone_Number, Location_Code) Values(@StaffNo,@First,@Surname,@Role,@Email,@Telephone,@Location)"
    conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TxtUsername.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TxtFirstName.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TxtSurname.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Role", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TxtRole.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TxtEmail.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telephone", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TxtTelephone.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DdlLocation.SelectedItem.Text.ToString
    conn.Open()
    recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    conn.Close()
    Try
        Membership.CreateUser(TxtUsername.Text, TxtPassword.Text)
        lblResult.Text = "Successfully created user " & TxtUsername.Text
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblResult.Text = "Error" & ex.ToString
    End Try
       End Sub
```

The exception comes up incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User' I have checked my database and all the values are the same Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USER is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). To use it as table name or column name you need to encapsulate it in square brackets

```
 Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT INTO [User] " & _ 
     "(Staff_No, First_Name, Surname, Position_Held, Email, Telephone_Number, Location_Code) " & _
     "Values(@StaffNo,@First,@Surname,@Role,@Email,@Telephone,@Location)"
```

I suggest to change this name because you will have this problem every time your need to write a query using that table.

Comment: Cheers saved me alot of time. I assumed it was something around those lines but just didn't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the error message is `Keyword` - `User` is a keyword, and so you need to [delimit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) it if you want to use it as an identifier:

```
Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT INTO [User](Staff_No, ...
```

Although usually, I'd recommend changing the name of the table to avoid [keywords](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) altogether, instead.

Answer (score 0):

User is Keyword of SQL Server.

Could you please add [] both side of user and try.

thanks

> Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT INTO [User](Staff_No, First_Name, Surname, Position_Held, Email, Telephone_Number, Location_Code) Values(@StaffNo,@First,@Surname,@Role,@Email,@Telephone,@Location)"